# Echo array_values from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am very new in PHP and I was checking whether all my controlers are in so how can I echo this? what I tried resulting nothing

```
 $controllers = array_intersect($json_api->get_controllers(), $active_controllers );

  $return = array(
    'json_api_version' => $version,
    'controllers' => array_values($controllers)
  );
echo $return['controllers']['controllers'];
```

Comment: Show us the result/content of `$json_api->get_controllers()` and `$active_controllers` please. Also, tell us what you want as an output.

Comment: either `print_r($return["controllers"]);` or `var_dump($return["controllers"]);` (as long as you only want to PRINT these) These are even before the hello world though, you should see a php tutorial as soon as possible in order to correctly procede into your project ;)

Comment: Also, what do you mean with *checking whether all my controlers are in*? If it means what I think it means, you want someting like `count($json_api->get_controllers()) === count($active_controllers)` instead.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => ipad
    [2] => city
) i got this result,what i actualy need is to assign city to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `print_r` function:

```
print_r($return['controllers']);
```

when you want read city you do:

```
$arr_controllers = $return['controllers'];
$key_2 = $arr_controllers[2];
```

where 2 is the key

Comment: Array ( [0] => core [1] => ipad [2] => city ) i got this result,what i actualy need is to assign city to a variable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the values of an array with a 
understandable format you should use `print_r()` instead of `echo` like so:

```
print_r($return['controllers']);
```

You can also use `var_dump()` to get some extra information about the fields, like the type and lenght.

If what you need is to asign a certain index of the array to a value just do something like this:

```
$variable = $return['controllers'][indexOfField]; // indexOfField=2 for city field
echo $variable;
```

For further information about `print_r()` check [the official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Comment: Array ( [0] => core [1] => ipad [2] => city ) i got this result,what i actualy need is to assign city to a variable

Comment: @Melvin Ok, I have already edited it, anyway try to edit a little bit your question to make it more clear :)